# Append text to lines in text document, using PHP

Tags: php, string, file, text, append

How do I append the following text to the start of new lines in a text document using PHP?

`Line 1: T: my text here` 
`Line 2: Z: my text here`
`Line 3: T: my text here`

etc.

Basically, alternate between T: and Z:.

Assume I use explode of some sort?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`file`](http://php.net/file) to get each line of the file. Then iterate each line, append your text and save the file using [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

```
<?php

$lines = file('input-file.txt');

$output = '';
$TorZ = 'T';
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $output .= $TorZ.': '.$line.PHP_EOL;

    if($TorZ == 'T')
        $TorZ = 'Z';
    else
        $TorZ = 'T';
}

file_put_contents('output.txt', $output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's in the file, use `file()` to read the file, you'll get array of lines. If it's a string, use `explode("\n", $string)`. If you don't know the separator, you can use `preg_split("/(\n|\r|\n\r)/", $string)`. Then loop over the elements of the array and prepend the string, then use `join("\n", $arr)` to convert array back to string. If you need to preserve separators, use `preg_split` as above with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option and skip delimiters when prepending strings.

If you used `file()` the line ends are already there, so use `file_put_contents("newfile", join('', $arr))` to write it back.